# Create dump of oracle in server and not in client

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, export

Can anyone tell me how to create the dump file in the server itself and not in the client side for oracle database i used `exp` and `expdp` but it stores the `.dmp` file in client C:.but i wanted it in the server itself.

Comment: Are you sure?  `exp` writes to the client but Data Pump writes to database directory objects, i.e. server directories.

Comment: `expdp` (ak "DataPump") ***will*** write the dump file on the server - there is no other option.

Comment: [Because Data Pump is server-based rather than client-based, dump files, log files, and SQL files are accessed relative to server-based directory paths.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10701/dp_overview.htm#i1009520)

Answer (score 1):

`expdp` creates `.dmp` file in the server filesystem. If you want to find where it is created,

```
select * from dba_directories
```

and search for the location of the directory object you have used as a parameter of `expdp`